# What does <button></button>{" "} mean in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following component.

If user clicked button with emoji, list of buttons should be hidden.

I have following component.

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  emoji: string,
  name: string
}

export function EmojiRating({ emoji, name }: Props) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{emoji} - {name} </span>
      {rating ? (
        <span>{rating}</span>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => setRating("")}></button>
          <button onClick={() => setRating("")}></button>
          <button onClick={() => setRating("")}></button>{" "}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Everything is working. Buttons are hidden with `{" "}`. But how does `{" "}` work in the line `<button onClick={() => setRating("")}></button>{" "}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a literal JS string inserted into your JSX. Your editor most likely automatically fixed a space character that was left on the last line.

Braces `{}` within JSX will be evaluated as JavaScript.

Comment: thank you. But what is sense use it in this component?

Comment: It has no need to be there and you can safely delete it. I think it was most likely just a typo/accident that your editor tried to correct.

Comment: A real use case would be to insert a string between two spans, or something along those lines, like `<span>Hello</span>{" "}<span>There</span>`. However, that's a bit of a stretch for "real" use case.